# How to model a transition system with SPIN

Tags: model-checking, spin, transition-systems

I am new to spin. I want to check whether a transition system satisfies the given LTL property. But I don't know how to model a transition system in promela.
For example, the transition system shown below has two states, and the initial state is s0. 
How to check whether the LTL property: <>q is satisfied. Does anybody know how to describe this problem in promela?  By the way, how to use the next operator of LTL in spin?
[image: transition system]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can model your automata by using labels, atomic blocks and gotos:

```
bool p, q;

init
{  
  s1:
    atomic {
      p = true;
      q = false;
    }
    goto s2;

  s2:
    atomic {
      p = false;
      q = true;
    }
}
```

To check your LTL property, place `ltl eventually_q { <>q };` at the end of your file and run Spin and the generated executable with `-a`.

If you place a property that doesn't hold at the end, for example, `ltl always_p { []p };`, you'll get the message `end state in claim reached` that indicates that the property has been violated.

About the next-operator: It is in conflict with the partial order reduction algorithm that Spin uses per default. Properties using the next-operator must be *stutter invariant*, otherwise, partial order reduction must be disabled. Read more at the end of [this man page](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/ltl.html).