# Using the ne(X)t operator in a SPIN ltl formula

Tags: model-checking, spin, promela

I am trying to define an ltl formula which uses the ne(X)t operator in SPIN. My problem is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712760/how-to-model-a-transition-system-with-spin) question. I have a state machine and I want to verify that if some statement *p* is true in state0, then some statement *q* is true in the next state, state1. The ltl formula looks like this:

`ltl p0 {p X q}`

When I attempt to generate the verifier using `spin -a test.pml` I get the following error:

`spin: test.pml:20, Error: syntax error saw 'X'`

I compiled SPIN with the -DNXT flag (as [this](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/ltl.html) suggested). I know that the ne(X)t operator cannot be tested with partial order reduction enabled. The only way I have found to disable partial order reduction is with the -DNOREDUCE flag when compiling the verifier. However, I can't even generate the verifier (pan.c) in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general structure of an **LTL** formula for which

> if some statement **p** is `true` in **state<sub>i</sub>**, then some statement **q** is `true` in the next state, **state<sub>i+1</sub>**

is the following one:

```
ltl p0 { [] (p -> X q) }
```

The formula `p -> X q` is verified by

- any state **S<sub>i</sub>** s.t. `p` is `false` in **S<sub>i</sub>**
- any state **S<sub>i</sub>** s.t. `p` is `true` in **S<sub>i</sub>** and `q` is `true` in **S<sub>i+1</sub>**, where **S<sub>i+1</sub>** is the successor of **S<sub>i</sub>** in the execution path currently being evaluated

The **globally** operator `[]` is required to make the **Model Checker** verify that the condition `p -> X q` holds for any state in the execution path. If you omit it, then the property `p -> X q` is only be checked for the initial state, which in the *99.99%* of cases is not what you want.

---

**EXAMPLE**

In the following model, if `cc` is even then process **counter** increases it by one, otherwise the process either terminates or decreases `cc` by one in a non-deterministic fashion.

The property that we want to check is that, whenever **counter** reaches a given **checkpoint** state and `cc` is even, after exactly 2 transitions `cc` is odd.

```cpp
byte cc = 0;

active proctype counter()
{
checkpoint:
    do
        :: cc % 2 == 0 -> cc++;
        :: else ->
            if
                :: cc--;
                :: break;
            fi;
    od;
}

#define even ( cc % 2 == 0 )
#define odd  ( cc % 2 == 1 )

ltl p0 { [] ( (counter[0]@checkpoint & even) -> X X odd) }
```

The ltl property `p0` is verified:

```sh
~$ spin -a test.pml
~$ gcc -DNXT -DNOREDUCE -o run pan.c
~$ ./run -a

(Spin Version 6.4.3 -- 16 December 2014)

Full statespace search for:
    never claim             + (p0)
    assertion violations    + (if within scope of claim)
    acceptance   cycles     + (fairness disabled)
    invalid end states  - (disabled by never claim)

State-vector 28 byte, depth reached 11, errors: 0
        8 states, stored (10 visited)
        2 states, matched
       12 transitions (= visited+matched)
        0 atomic steps
hash conflicts:         0 (resolved)

Stats on memory usage (in Megabytes):
    0.000   equivalent memory usage for states (stored*(State-vector + overhead))
    0.289   actual memory usage for states
  128.000   memory used for hash table (-w24)
    0.534   memory used for DFS stack (-m10000)
  128.730   total actual memory usage


unreached in proctype counter
    (0 of 11 states)
unreached in claim p0
    _spin_nvr.tmp:16, state 20, "-end-"
    (1 of 20 states)

pan: elapsed time 0 seconds
```

Things to note:

- in this example, the use of the **label** `checkpoint:` is completely optional. The same result could have been obtained using the *ltl formula* `{ [] ( even -> X X odd) }`. However, **labels** are quite frequently used in the context of formulas with the structure `[] (p -> X g)`, so I thought it would be useful to push one inside my example with some empty pretext.
- I would normally prefer the weaker `F odd` condition to the stronger statement `X X odd`, unless that isn't possible/advisable due to the nature of the property being verified. In fact, with **Spin** it is not easy to guess with a single glance how many transitions occur from one *statement* to the other, since *AFAIK* the *model* normally undergoes a number of optimisations to remove/merge states with one another.

Comment: I am having some trouble understand what exactly constitutes a transition. Is it only when the state changes? If so, then wouldn't X X (2 transitions) include the option of cc = 0 -> cc++ -> cc-- resulting in state cc = 0, which would violate (X X odd)? Or, is it any executable statement, in which case the only 2 transitions from checkpoint are cc = 0 -> (cc% 2 == 0) -> cc++?

Comment: @cmoses *no*, because a state *loosely* corresponds to a **statement** in your *Promela* code (that is, the state information includes a reference to the statement *"being executed"*), so you have to take that into account too; it takes 4 transitions to make `cc` again even, you can test it by playing with the *ltl formula* in the example. You should use option `-o3` to prevent statement merging in the verifier, this might help matching states with statements in the model.